# Is there a security proof for the Triple-DES construction in the ideal cipher model?

Tags: provable-security, random-oracle-model, 3des

Suppose one has an ideal block cipher

$E \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^k \times \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; D \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^k \times \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w$.

One can obviously follow the [Triple-DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) construction with that block cipher and [keying option $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options), to get the block ciphers

$\operatorname{enc}_n \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^{(4-n)\cdot k} \times \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; \operatorname{dec}_n \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^{(4-n)\cdot k} \times \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^w$.

One can easily show that is takes $\:$[$\Theta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)$\left(2^k\right)\:$ queries to $E$ and $D$ to break the security of $E\hspace{.02 in}$.

Regardless of which keying option is used, $\:\operatorname{enc}_n\:$ will be at least that secure.

For $\:n\in \{\hspace{-0.02 in}1,\hspace{-0.02 in}2\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$, is it known that $\:\operatorname{enc}_n\:$ will be a [PRP family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) against adversaries that can make significantly *more* than $2^k$ queries to $E$ and $D\hspace{.03 in}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The following papers should be exactly what you are looking for.

The following paper shows that the answer is "Yes" and provides evidence that 3-key Triple DES is more secure than single DES:

- [Code-Based Game-Playing Proofs and the Security of Triple Encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/331.pdf).
  Mihir Bellare, Phillip Rogaway.  IACR ePrint 2004/331.  (Full version of a paper published at Eurocrypt 2006.)

They show that, in the ideal cipher model, the adversary must make more than about $2^{78}$ chosen-plaintext/ciphertext queries to have a reasonable chance at distinguishing 3-key Triple DES from a random permutation.  This not too far off from the best known attack on 3-key Triple DES (which requires about $2^{90}$ queries), and shows that 3-key Triple DES is significantly more secure than single DES (again, in the ideal cipher model).

There is prior work by Aiello et al. that analyzes 2-key Triple DES in the ideal cipher; see the related work section of the Bellare et al. paper for a citation and discussion.

There is also subsequent work that re-proves the result on 3-key Triple DES in a simpler form, and analyzes 5DES and longer cascades as well:

- [Cascade Encryption Revisited](http://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2009/59120035/59120035.pdf).
  Peter Gazi, Ueli Maurer.  Asiacrypt 2009.

Comment: The Aiello paper only obtains the same bound for 2-key 3DES as it obtains for "double DES". $\hspace{.98 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer, I thought you were curious about whether 2-key 3DES is more secure than single DES (rather than whether it's more secure than double DES), and I believe the Aiello paper does demonstrate one sense in which it is.  Anyway, it's not important -- if the Aiello paper isn't what you were looking for, I'm fine with that!  The other papers should still be useful.